# Flutter google sign in how to listen for password change

Tags: flutter, passwords, google-signin

I am currently developing a flutter app with Google sign in, everything works, but don't know how to make the app listen continuously for password change, when the user change his/her password, the app should log out automatically.

Comment: Password change where? on google?  They arent going to tell you that.

Comment: @DaImTo, yes, when the Google password is changed, the flutter app should know it and log out the user. For example, if user uses web to change his/her password and is still login in an app.

Comment: I dont think google supports back channel logout in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register for events via Cross Account Protection: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc.

You will be able to register to receive specific events like account_disabled or account_credential_change_required: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#supported_event_types